# CDI: Two producers

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have to producers:

```
@Produces 
public IPaymentGateway getStripePaymentGateway(@StripeApiKey final String apiKey) {
   return new StripeFluentAPI(apiKey);
}

@Produces
public IPaymentGateway getStripePaymentGatewayProxy() {
    IPaymentGateway gateway = mock(IPaymentGateway.class);
    ICustomer customer = mock(ICustomer.class);

    when(gateway.customer()).thenReturn(customer);

    return gateway;
}
```

The first one returns a real implementation of my `IPaymentGateway`. By other side, the second one returns a proxied object.

I'm using an `@ApplicationScoped` object in order to know if the gateway has to be enabled or disabled:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationResources {
    public boolean isPaymentGatewayEnabled() {
        return paymentGatewayEnabled;
    }
}
```

So, I'd like to know how to select on or other producers according `isPaymentGatewayEnabled` value.

Comment: You can have a single method producing the `IPaymentGateway` and add the `ConfigurationResources` as a parameter of this method. Then you can produce either the "real" bean or the mock dependending on the `isPaymentGatewayEnabled` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ConfigurationResources` is a CDI bean (`@ApplicationScoped`) it is also injectable. You can make use of that and go for producer injection in approximately this way:

```
@Produces 
public IPaymentGateway getStripePaymentGateway(@StripeApiKey final String apiKey, ConfigurationResources configResource) {
   if (configResource.isEnabled()) {
     return new StripeFluentAPI(apiKey);
   } else {
     IPaymentGateway gateway = mock(IPaymentGateway.class);
     ICustomer customer = mock(ICustomer.class);
     when(gateway.customer()).thenReturn(customer);
     return gateway;
   }
}
```

Therefore, this will create a result based on `configResource.isEnabled()`.